# differentiability $|f(x)|$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If a given function $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=a$, then is $|f(x)|$ necessarily differentiable at $x=a$?

What about the the opposite direction of the statement (I'm quite sure that it isn't true, just want to make sure).

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

No to both. $f(x) = x$ is differentiable at $x = 0$, but $|x|$ is not. The sign function
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x \geq 0 \\ -1 & \text{if } x < 0 \end{cases}$$
is not even continuous at $0$, but $|f(x)| = 1$ for all $x$, therefore $|f|$ is differentiable everywhere.

Comment: and if I'm told that a≠0, does it change anything?

Comment: @HaleyJohns No, the same goes for $f(x) = |x-a|$ at $x = a$.

Comment: You should rather have $f(a) \ne 0$ @HaleyJohns